# Folder Structure in CloudPage Personalized URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, url, cloudpage

In the classic Microsites, we were able to add a "folder"-like structure to the personalized URL, i.e. https://pages.s7.exacttarget.com/foldername/something/

But in CloudPages, if you try to do the same thing it doesn't work. After publishing the page , the page shows a "Bad Request." But removing the "folders" in the personalized URL for the same page corrects it.

Has anyone been able to do this? It makes for easier to organize paths in the URL rather than having everything in the root domain.

Comment: opened a support case, this is very relevant for tracking that assumes page folders. Will update with the reply.

Comment: Any updates @JonasLamberty?

Comment: yes! Sorry. Writing a reply now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.
From the support answer I received last year, simple message:

> "we won't be able to add "/" slash in Custom URL.

Comment: Just posted it as an idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PdvkQAC